# How can I filter multiple tabs/sheets in google sheet

Tags: excel, filter, google-sheets-formula

Can anybody help me here please? I want to know how can I filter multiple tabs (C1-C19) in my sheet. Here is what I've done:

I created a sheet that would store all the response in my google form (registration form for an event). Each participant will receive a TANK NUMBER, and each Tank Number is formatted according to their Category (C1-C19)[![enter image description here

The FOR PAYMENT VALIDATION tab is like a summary of all the participants arranged by the date they register. Once their payment has been validated(Column P), their information will be added to the tab of their chosen Sub Category where a TANK NUMBER will be automatically assigned to them. On the FOR PAYMENT VALIDATION tab, I added a column for Tank Number *(please ignore the data there, I have tried some formula but no luck)*. The purpose of this is for the Event Organizer to be already informed of the tank number once he validated the payment so he can give the tank number to the participant. I've assigned a unique number for each participant (Column A: PUN), so I can pull out their tank numbers from c1-c19 tabs using their PUN.
][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A4aQK.jpg)][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A4aQK.jpg)

[image]

[image]

So to do that, I want to filter all the tabs (c1-c19) where the PUN from the FOR PAYMENT VALIDATION tab is equal to the PUN contained in one of the tabs (c1-c19) then once it finds out where, it will pull out the Tank Number assigned.

I don't know what to do anymore. I've tried query, but filter is the function that gave me the closest result. However, I don't know how to filter all the tabs (c1-c19) in one go. I was thinking of putting a Filter function inside the If or Iferror, but got no clue how to do it. Below is the formula I have tried.

```
=FILTER('C1'!A2:A8,'C1'!B2:B8=A5)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to create an array:

```
={'C1'!A2:A8; 'C2'!A2:A8; 'C3'!A2:A8}
```

to stack columns from different sheets under one virtual column. this can be then imputed as range into formula:

```
=FILTER({'C1'!A2:A8; 'C2'!A2:A8; 'C3'!A2:A8},
        {'C1'!B2:B8; 'C2'!B2:B8; 'C3'!B2:B8}=A5)
```

if you want to use QUERY (if A5 is numeric value) try:

```
=QUERY({'C1'!A2:B8; 'C2'!A2:B8; 'C3'!A2:B8}, 
 "select Col1 where Col2 = "&A5)
```

or like this if A5 is formated as plain text:

```
=QUERY({'C1'!A2:B8; 'C2'!A2:B8; 'C3'!A2:B8}, 
 "select Col1 where Col2 = '"&A5&"'")
```

or if you are not sure go for:

```
=INDEX(QUERY(TO_TEXT({'C1'!A2:B8; 'C2'!A2:B8; 'C3'!A2:B8}), 
 "select Col1 where Col2 = '"&A5&"'"))
```